# Ruby Detect method

Tags: ruby, detect

Select makes sense. But can someone explain .detect to me? I don't understand these data.

```
>> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7].detect { |x| x.between?(3,4) }
=> 3
>> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7].detect { |x| x.between?(3,6) }
=> 3
>> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7].detect { |x| x.between?(3,7) }
=> 3
>> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7].detect { |x| x.between?(2,7) }
=> 2
>> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7].detect { |x| x.between?(1,7) }
=> 1
>> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7].detect { |x| x.between?(6,7) }
=> 6
>> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7].select { |x| x.between?(6,7) }
=> [6, 7]
>> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7].select { |x| x.between?(1,7) }
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Detect returns the first item in the list for which the block returns TRUE. Your first example:

```
>> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7].detect { |x| x.between?(3,4) }
=> 3
```

Returns `3` because that is the first item in the list that returns TRUE for the expression `x.between?(3,4)`.

`detect` stops iterating after the condition returns true for the first time. `select` will iterate until the end of the input list is reached and returns all of the items where the block returned true.

Comment: Obligatory RubyDoc link: http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003123

Comment: An alias for 'detect' is 'find'. For me it is easier to understand the semantics of the method if I think about it as 'find'.

Comment: Using "detect" and "find" interchangably does not appear to be correct however.  If you check the ruby docs, if fact it points out in both the detect & find example code that they behave differently. It is in fact difficult to figure out the difference between "find" and "detect" because the explanatory text is ~exactly~ the same for both methods, but the explanatory methods differ.
http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-find

Comment: @PaulDacus However when you expend the source code, #detect points to enum_find(...). So I assume #detect is an alias for #find here.

Comment: @PaulDacus The explanatory methods from `detect` and `find` in RubyDocs behave differently because they're being called by different objects: `(1..10)` vs `(1..100)`.

Comment: There's also a missconception in the docs. The docs say `first for which block is not false`, which implies that you may return that value or even `nil` for a method which requires boolean. Instead, if it accepts truthy/falsy values, it should say so.

Answer (score 11):

detect just returns the first value that satisfies the predicate, if any, nil otherwise. `select` returns all the values that satisfy the predicate. `a.detect { p }` is analogous to `a.select { p }[0]`

```
 irb(main):001:0> [1,2,3].detect { true }
 => 1
 irb(main):002:0> [1,2,3].detect { false }
 => nil
 irb(main):003:0> [1,2,3].detect { |x| x % 2 == 0 }
 => 2
```

Answer (score 5):

The ruby-docs are a great ressource when you want to learn about the methods.

[Enumerable#detect](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003123)

Answer (score 4):

`find` and `detect` will always either return a single object or they will return `nil` if nothing is matched:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7].detect { |x| x.between?(1,7) }
=> 1
```

`find_all` and `select` will return an array of things that it finds that match:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7].select { |x| x.between?(1,7) }
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

[Reference Link](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#)